# Checking if a list has all the contents of another

Tags: c#, list, integer

Let's say I have a list of ints called `List<int> List1 = new() {1,2,3,4}` and `List<int> List2 = new() {2,3,4}`.

I need to check if List2 has everything List1 has. Keep in mind that list lengths may vary.

I have no idea on how to make it. Searching on the internet didnt really help.

Comment: `List1<int> {1,2,3,4}` and `List2<int> {2,3,4}` doesn't compile.

Comment: Search the All IEnumerable extension and the Contains method for a List<T>

Comment: @Deleted I literally typed it outside of an IDE manually without thinking. It was just to give an idea on what I was doing...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use HashSet for the first set of values and just iterate over the second one to check whether the iterator value exists in the created HashSet or not:

```cs
var set = new HashSet<int>(list1);
var result = list2.All(item => set.Contains(item));
```

If you don't want to use HashSet, you can do the same thing with LINQ, but with worse performance:

```cs
var result = list2.All(il2 => list1.Any(il1 => il1 == il2));
```

or

```cs
var result = !list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

Comment: Every solution you provided gives me a different output. When checked, none gave me the correct answer.

Just so you will know what I am doing. Im attempting myself to do Advent of Code day 4 part 1 at the moment. I split input (ex. 17-99,18-24) by '-' and then by ',' to get the numbers,  make a list with everything inbetween them, and then want to check if items in list1 are in list2 (the task here is to find which pairs have the same sectors, in the example I've provided, it should return true, because 18 and 24 are inbetween 17 and 99).

Comment: (Another comment because character limit). If theres any better way of doing this, let me know. If you need, here's my code until now https://pastebin.com/eMsRq4Kv .

Comment: Well, it's a completely different task if we compare it to the original question... 
To be honest, I don't think that you have to create a list of the numbers to check it, because you have min and max range limits, so why don't you just use it to compare overlapping one range with another?

Comment: Actually, you can simplify the solution with the following check:
var containsSameTimes = secondGroupsSectionMin >= firstGroupsSectionMin && secondGroupsSectionMax <= firstGroupsSectionMax;

In that case, you don't need to populate two lists with the range values at all. If you want to solve this problem only with LINQ, the answer still works cause it gives true for the given example.

Comment: And of course, if firstGroupSectors can be a subset of secondGroupSectors, you need to extend the check in the following way:
(secondGroupsSectionMin >= firstGroupsSectionMin && secondGroupsSectionMax <= firstGroupsSectionMax) || (firstGroupsSectionMin >= secondGroupsSectionMin && firstGroupsSectionMax <= secondGroupsSectionMax)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code, so you need to check whether `ls2` is a subset of `ls1`.

```
bool isSubset = !ls2.Except(ls1).Any();
```